# How can I add participants in a massive way to a conference?

Tags: circuit-sdk

we need to add a large number of students to the conference or group regardless of whether they are registered in circuit

Can be done?
What method could I use?

we use JS SDK

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [addParticipant](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_addParticipant) to add multiple participants to a conversation.

Since you specify "conference" I am not sure if you are referring to adding participants to an ongoing call. If that is the case you can use [addParticipantToCall](https://circuitsandbox.net/sdk/classes/Client.html#method_addParticipantToCall). Using this API you can add members or even dial out users using a phone number, assuming telephony is enabled on your tenant.

Comment: this example don't show with "email" @RogerUrscheler just with number o userIds

Comment: Let's start from the beginning then. Are you trying to add participants to an ongoing call/conference, or to a conversation?

Comment: Circuit users can be dialed-out via their email or userId via API addParticipantToCall. Only one user can be dialed out at a time.    

Non-Circuit users cannot be dialed out to their Circuit client since their aren't a Circuit user (other than a PSTN call). But you can send them guest link (get via getConversationDetails).   

Any user, registered or not ca be dialed out via their phone number during an ongoing call (API addParticipantToCall), assuming the tenant has telephony enabled.